# JSON PHP Output Logic

Tags: php, json

I am using this script in PHP to capture google products through ZenSerp. I can get an output with all the terms.
Example;

1. Title
2. Description
3. Price
4. Image
5. URL Link

Is there a way to print

1.price
2.title
3.description

on another page?
thanks.

```
<?php 



$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$data = [
   "q" => "Tools",
   "tbm" => "shop",
   "device" => "desktop",
   "location" => "Manhattan,New York,United States",
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?" . http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "apikey: XXXX",
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response);


echo '<pre>' . var_export($json, true) . '</pre>';


?>
```

Output:

```
 (object) array(
       'title' => 'Craftsman 320-Piece Mechanic S Tool Set',
       'link' => '/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjn5sb54NDtAhXHfysKHWT9BIIYABBXGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_1kzP9frQqO7uULjK4LGcDJkpuuGA&ctype=46&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjP9cL54NDtAhUBjeYKHaqqBzgQ_-QECL8H&adurl=',
       'description' => 'Mechanic · CRAFTSMAN',
       'price' => '$149.99',
       'source' => 'Sears',
       'stars' => 4.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375,
       'reviews' => 1084,
       'thumbnail' => 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/',
       'extensions' => 
      array (
      ),
       'product_id' => '13276029442981215243',
       'price_parsed' => 
      (object) array(
         'currency' => 'USD',
         'value' => 149.990000000000009094947017729282379150390625,
```

Comment: How is this fetch initiated and how is this page that does the fetching connected to the other page where you want to use the results?

Comment: I am using the ZenSerp service  through a key I am connected to their site. that script captures google products and prints them in php.

Comment: I would like to print the result in an html page Using only the terms; Title, Description, Price

Comment: _Title, Description, Price_ are not returned, where do they come from?

Comment: Post updated, sorry.

Comment: Maybe my questions weren't clear. When I asked about how is it initiated, I meant what is calling this script? Do you open a page or maybe do an AJAX call? And how do you expect to transfer these values over to another page? Is this something a user would have to initiate or should the user never see this page where you fetch the data?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Anyway, now to generate the output, I open the "index.php" page and it returns the values

This is the example link.

http://testapi.kenix.it/index.php

Comment: Just include this page on the other page and do `echo $jon->price;` etc...